# Rounding a number with printf in java?

Tags: java, printf

i am trying to use System.out.printf to round a very large number to 2 decimal places. This is the code i am using:

```
System.out.printf(" %1.2f = overpayment:$" + overpayment);
```

I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%1.2f'
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)
```

I am under the impression that %f is the format specifier and %1.2f is used for a floating point number with 2 digits after the decimal.
I am trying to round 4.4260494195128784E-4 to 4.43. Thank you

Since I am getting under a cent for my overpayment, I think i have the wrong formula to calculate it. Does anyone have an idea on how to attain overpayment of a loan? The overpayment value should be 4.43. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class CreditCardPayoff {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    double principle;
    double annualInterestRate;
    double monthlyPayment;
    double numerator;
    double denominator;
    double monthsToPayOff;
    double monthsToPayOffCeiled;
    double totalAmountPaid;
    double totalInterestPaid;
    double overpayment;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    principle = keyboard.nextDouble();
    annualInterestRate = keyboard.nextDouble();
    monthlyPayment = keyboard.nextDouble();

    numerator = Math.log(monthlyPayment) - Math.log(monthlyPayment-
            (annualInterestRate / 1200.00) * principle);
    denominator = Math.log((annualInterestRate/1200.00) + 1.0);
            monthsToPayOff = numerator/denominator;

    monthsToPayOffCeiled = Math.ceil(monthsToPayOff);

    totalAmountPaid = monthsToPayOffCeiled * monthlyPayment;

    totalInterestPaid = totalAmountPaid - principle;


    overpayment = (monthsToPayOffCeiled - monthsToPayOff)/monthlyPayment;




    System.out.println("Principle:" + principle);
    System.out.println("Annual Interest Rate:" + annualInterestRate);
    System.out.println("Monthly Payment:" + monthlyPayment);

    System.out.println("Months Needed To Pay Off:" + (int)monthsToPayOffCeiled);
    System.out.println("Total Amount Paid: $" + totalAmountPaid);
    System.out.println("Total Interest Paid: $" + totalInterestPaid);
    System.out.printf("overpayment: $%1.2f ", overpayment);


}
```

}

My method to calculate overpayment, obtain difference between monthsToPayOff and monthsToPayOffCeil (ceiling) then divide by monthly payment. This got me 4.4260494195128784E-4.

Comment: Did you look at any examples or documentation about how to use `printf`?

Comment: `4.4260494195128784E-4` is not a very large number; it's a small number.  And even if you use `printf` properly, you'll get `0.00`.

Comment: 2 digits after the decimal? But u said u want the output 4.3

Comment: Excuse me, sorry I updated it to 4.43.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how you use `printf`.

```
System.out.printf("%1.2f and %d", 1.25f, 1000);
```

Knowing this, you can also add extra formatting:

```
printf( "$%.2f", overpayed );
```

Inside of the format string you can specify your data types, and then each one is passed as an argument thereafter.

Comment: I don't think the OP has the placeholder where they intend for it to be, guessing from the location of the dollar sign.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) you do not concatenate the values for the placeholders with the format string, but rather pass them as parameters:

```
System.out.printf("overpayment: $%1.2f", overpayment);
```

Comment: How come I am getting $0.00 as my result? Am I using the wrong format specifier?

Comment: @awrath No, it is because the number is [less than one cent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation).

Answer (score 0):

`printf` takes one argument for every format specifier (see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)). In Java arguments are separated by commas (`,`).

So, in your example, instead of a `+` that concatenate two strings (a string and a number into a string, to be precise), you should use a comma:

```
System.out.printf(" %1.2f = overpayment:$", overpayment);
```